# twig form_widget value variable doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, twig

```
{{ form_widget(form.category,{value:"3"}) }} //works!!
{{ form_widget(form.category,{value:'3'}) }} //works!!
{{ form_widget(form.category,{value:3}) }} // doesn't work !!

{{lastCatId}} // echos 3 !!!

{{ form_widget(form.category,{value:"lastCatId"}) }} //doesn't work ???
{{ form_widget(form.category,{value:'lastCatId'}) }} //doesn't work ???
```

I know after symfony 2.3. Value has to be quoted or double quoted. But I don't know why the variable doesnt work

Comment: What is the error? Doesnt work does not really help... I could assaume that value has to be an integer? Otherwise no idea if you do not copy the error-message!

Comment: I am sorry its not an error, I am trying to set "selected" on the select form. with 3 it works and defaults to number 3 but with the variable it doesn't default

Answer (score 2):

never mind. I found the problem

{{ form_widget(form.category,{'value' : lastCatId|number_format }) }}

I had to cast it to int.